# Map line breaks in sentence to another list

Tags: python, nltk

In a file I have text like so with random line breaks:

```
Spencer J. Volk, president and CEO of this company, was elected a director. 
Mr. Volk, 55 years old, succeeds Duncan Dwight, 
who retired in September.
```

I am using nltk's sentence tokenizer to find sentences and then tagging words in those sentences with Part of Speech tags. For example, after tagging, I get output like this (a list of word,tag tuples for each word in the sentence):

```
[('Spencer', u'NNP'), ('J.', u'NNP'), ('Volk', u'NNP'), ('president', u'NN'), ('and', u'CC'), ('CEO', u'NN'), ('of', u'IN'), ('this', u'DT'), ('company', u'NN'), ('was', u'VBD'), ('elected', u'VBN'), ('a', u'DT'), ('director', u'NN')]

[('Mr.', u'NNP'), ('Volk', u'NNP'), ('55', u'CD'), ('years', u'NNS'), ('old', u'JJ'), ('succeeds', u'VBZ'), ('Duncan', u'NNP'), ('Dwight', u'NNP'), ('who', u'WP'), ('retired', u'VBD'), ('in', u'IN'), ('September', u'NNP')]
```

But now I want to write the tags in another file **with the same line breaks** as were there in the original file I read the text from. For the above example, it would be something like:

```
NNP NNP NNP NN CC NN IN DT NN VBD VBN DT NN
NNP NNP CD NNS JJ VBZ NNP NNP
WP VBD IN NNP
```

I can get the tags and everything in this form, but how do I associate the original line breaks to breaks in the tag list?

One way to do it is to split each sentence, find the index of `\n` hoping that each split would correspond to a word in the sentence (which might not always be true) and then break the tag list at that index. This is more like a hack and fails in many scenarios. What would be a more robust way to achieve this?

Comment: why did you remove the punctuations? they're pretty useful.

Comment: @alvas I didn't. The tagger I was using did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting puzzle. First, note that `nltk.sent_tokenize()` will preserve newlines that are *inside* a sentence:

```
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for s in sents:
    print(repr(s))
```

So to interleave POS tags with newlines, you can walk down a sentence one token at a time and check for newlines between them:

```
def process_sent(sent):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))

    for word, tag in tagged:
        pre, _, post = sent.partition(word)
        if "\n" in pre:
            print("\n", end="")
        print(tag, end=" ")
        sent = post # advance to the next word
    if "\n" in post:
        print("\n", end="")
```

I'm not quite sure why, but `nltk.sent_tokenize()` discards newlines that occur *between* sentence boundaries. So we need to look for them too. Fortunately, we can use exactly the same algorithm: walk down the full text one sentence at a time, and check for newlines between them.

```
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for s in sents:
    pre, _, post = text.partition(s)
    if "\n" in pre:
        print("\n", end="")
    process_sent(s)
    text = post  # Advance to the next sentence -- munges `text` so use another var if it matters.

if "\n" in post:
    print("\n", end="")
```

PS. That should do it, except that you'll only get *one* newline in the output wherever there are several adjacent ones. If you care about this, replace `if "\n" in pre: print("\n", end="")` with calls to this:

```
def nlretain(txt):
    """Output as many newlines as there are in `txt`"""
     print("\n"*txt.count("\n"), end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the line break and using the `sent_tokenize`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, sent_tokenize
>>> text = """Spencer J. Volk, president and CEO of this company, was elected a director. 
... Mr. Volk, 55 years old, succeeds Duncan Dwight, ... who retired in September. """>>> 
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, sent_tokenize>>> text = """Spencer J. Volk, president and CEO of this company, was elected a director. 
... Mr. Volk, 55 years old, succeeds Duncan Dwight, ... who retired in September. """>>> 
>>> text = " ".join(i for i in text.split('\n'))
>>> tagged_text = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
>>> for sent in tagged_text:
...     poses = " ".join(pos for word, pos in sent)
...     print poses
... 
NN NNP NNP , NN CC NNP IN DT NN , VBD VBN DT NN .
NNP NNP , CD NNS JJ , NNS NNP NNP , WP VBN IN NNP .
```

Noting line breaks:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = """Spencer J. Volk, president and CEO of this company, was elected a director. 
... Mr. Volk, 55 years old, succeeds Duncan Dwight, 
... who retired in September. """
>>> 
>>> tagged_text = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) for sent in text.split('\n')]
>>> for sent in tagged_text:
...     poses = " ".join(pos for word, pos in sent)
...     print poses
... 
NN NNP NNP , NN CC NNP IN DT NN , VBD VBN DT NN .
NNP NNP , CD NNS JJ , NNS NNP NNP ,
WP VBN IN NNP .
```

You realized that the tokenizer didn't make a difference when in a proper sentence. It's the contextual information used by the POS tagger is weaker than the default tag for the word, so it didn't really matter whether you use `sent_tokenize` and then splitting up the non-sentence again.

---

If you want to `sent_tokenize` and then split the tags the `\n` as of the original te

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = """Spencer J. Volk, president and CEO of this company, was elected a director. 
... Mr. Volk, 55 years old, succeeds Duncan Dwight, 
... who retired in September. """

>>> sent_lens = [len(word_tokenize(line)) for line in text.split('\n')]
>>> sent_lens
[16, 11, 5]
>>> tagged_text = [[pos for word,pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(line))] for line in sent_tokenize(text)]
>>> for l in sent_lens:
...     sum = 0
...     for pos in list(chain(*tagged_text))[sum:sum+l]:
...             print pos,
...             sum = sum+l
...     print
... 
NN NNP NNP , NN CC NNP IN DT NN , VBD VBN DT NN .
NN NNP NNP , NN CC NNP IN DT NN ,
NN NNP NNP , NN
```

Comment: Well in this case the tags weren't different. But that's not the question. I am required to run the tagger on the sentence as a whole. Splitting the text and running the tagger on each line is trivial. The problem really is how would you achieve the second result if you run the tagger with `sent_tokenize` like you did in the first example.